# PrimeFaces OneRadio + "spacebar" key

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, radio-button

I have added radio buttons to various forms and even though I can focus on the radio buttons with "tab" I can not choose them pressing "spacebar". 
The arrow keys work so I can circle between the two radio buttons I have, but I need the "spacebar" functionality. With normal  this works ok, not with  though.

Is this some kind of bug or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Primefaces RadioButtons are customized to display the theme oriented RadioButton,the Space Bar wont Work.
If you want the space bar to work you are gonna have to give up the theme oriented style of RadioButton. And use the native style (Browser Default Style) on radiobuttons.
You can do that using **plain** attribute as follows:

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="customRadio" plain="true">
```

Comment: @Andy: I don't think so. If you look at the generated HTML from p:selectOneRadio . It is actually generating <div> with theme oriented radio button image in it, which is making <option> tag. I never tried to select the <div> with KeyPressEvent(space-bar). So I don't think its possible with either Javascript or Jquery.